# Should i create separate Android fragment for each independent piece of logic?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have been doing some coding using Angular and i really like the way in which you create a component for every piece of reusable logic or something that encapsulates independent logic. I think this allows us to write reusable and clean code. My question is if its efficient to do the same on Android? For example instead of having a lot of stuff in a single Activity or Fragment , i intend to split it into multiple fragments each coordinating with the other using well defined interfaces.

Is this efficient and a good approach? I have not tried this before so would like to read some opinions.

Comment: Maybe, it really depends, Fragments are (I believe) more complex than an angular component. Keep in mind there are also views which have less overhead.
Fragments have their own lifecyle and interactions with the backstack.

Comment: You should use one fragment (not separating into several) and create a Clean Architecture + MVVM / MVP. If you will have several fragments, how do you locate them in one layout (Activity)?